# How to efficiently replace items between Dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ages':[20, 22, 57], 'Label':[1,1,2]})
label_df = pd.DataFrame({'Label':[1,2,3], 'Description':['Young','Old','Very Old']})
```

I want to replace the label values in df to the description in label_df

Wanted result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ages':[20, 22, 57], 'Label':['Young','Young','Old']})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `Series` by `label_df`:

```
df['Label'] = df['Label'].map(label_df.set_index('Label')['Description'])
print (df)
   Ages  Label
0    20  Young
1    22  Young
2    57    Old
```

Comment: What would happen if there is no match between the indexes, what would map do?

Comment: @Moshe then is returned NaN

Answer (score 1):

simple use merge

```py
df['Label'] = df.merge(label_df,on='Label')['Description']
```

```
    Ages    Label
0   20  Young
1   22  Young
2   57  Old
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging

Comment: That's great, but I guess that it would not work in a situation where column name is not equal, for example 'Label' and 'Age_Label', right ?

Comment: if column name not the same.you can use left_on and right_on