# How to use pandas map() function, without overwriting items that do not match?

Tags: python, pandas

In my previous question here : [How to efficiently replace items between Dataframes in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67985945/how-to-efficiently-replace-items-between-dataframes-in-pandas/67986050?noredirect=1#comment120168646_67986050)

I got a solution with map() function that works, but it overrides items that do no match.

In case I have 2 df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ages':[20, 22, 57, 250], 'Label':[1,1,2,7]})
label_df = pd.DataFrame({'Label':[1,2,3], 'Description':['Young','Old','Very Old']})
```

I want to replace the label values in df to the description in label_df, but if there is no match between the indexes, keep the original value.

What I am getting with `df['Label'] = df['Label'].map(label_df.set_index('Label')['Description'])`

```
{'Ages':[20, 22, 57, 250], 'Label':['Young','Young','Old', nan]}
```

Wanted result:

```
{'Ages':[20, 22, 57, 250], 'Label':['Young','Young','Old', 7]}
```

Comment: You want the Non-Exhaustive Mapping in JohnE's solution. If you need a non-exhaustive mapping that sets things to `NaN` like `'Missing'` see my solution there.

Answer (score 7):

You can further use [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with original column after `.map()` to reinstate the original values in case of no match, as follows:

```
df['Label'] = df['Label'].map(label_df.set_index('Label')['Description']).fillna(df['Label'])
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) which does not set non-match to `NaN` (retain non-match values), as follows:

```
df['Label'] = df['Label'].replace(dict(zip(label_df['Label'], label_df['Description'])))
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   Ages  Label
0    20  Young
1    22  Young
2    57    Old
3   250      7
```